# Forcing columns to remain on the same page in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have one a4paper that has been divided up so that 2/3s of it is one column on the left, 1/3 is another on the right. I have just a few more things to add to both and then I am done but when I add data to my right hand column now, it automatically separates from the right hand column and goes to the next page. I need to force them to stay together, how would I do so?

Note: I am using Jan Kuster's "Sidebar CV" template on Overleaf

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4]{article}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}      

\geometry{top=1cm, bottom=-.6cm, left=0.4cm, right=1cm}     

\setlength{\headheight}{-5pt}       

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{multicol}           
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\mpwidth}{\linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxsep}

% This begins the first section
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{\begin{minipage}[c][0.95\textheight][t]{0.69\linewidth}
```

[The columns in the two photos should be on the same page, with the smaller column on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iz14.png)
[This should be to the right of the other column in the previous photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjjYH.png)

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You must realize that nobody can answer your question without an example. There are many ways to layout several columns in latex: minipages, twocolumm option of classes likes article, the multicol package which is very popular, the paracol package, and so on.   How can we know what you use and what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so very hacky fix... but what I ended up doing was resizing the paper I was using. So initially I was using A4 paper instead of Letter, with adjusted sizes for the respective minipages being used. I resized both and trimmed the minipage widths, and that solved my issue.